# Join based only on condition python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to join but only in cases where a certain other condition is `True`

I have a DataFrame `df1` that looks like this

```
ID    Bool   Val
1111  True   AAA
2222  False  BBB
3333  True   CCC
4444  False  DDD
```

I then have another DataFrame `df2` like this

```
ID    Val
1111  EEE
3333  FFF
5555  GGG
```

And I want to overwrite the `Val` column in `df1` where the `ID` match and the `Bool` is `True`. This would look like this

```
ID    Bool   Val
1111  True   EEE 
2222  False  BBB
3333  True   FFF
4444  False  DDD
```

As you can see the `AAA` and `CCC` have been overwritten.

I am thinking of doing this with an `if` statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` to select the rows of df1 where `'bool'` column is True ,also use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to assign correctly:

```
b=df1['Bool']
df1.loc[b,'Val']=df1.loc[b,'ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['Val'])
print(df1)

     ID   Bool  Val
0  1111   True  EEE
1  2222  False  BBB
2  3333   True  FFF
3  4444  False  DDD
```

Also you can use [pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df1.loc[b,'Val']=df1.loc[b,'ID'].replace(df2.set_index('ID')['Val'])
```